# Concatenar texto em um ProgressDialog

Tags: android

#### Situação

Tenho um seguinte `ProgressDialog` definido com `STYLE_HORIZONTAL` no qual é executado após obter o tamanho de um *download* de um arquivo. Desta forma, defino o seu tamanho usando `.setMax(tamanho)`. Após a definição do tamanho, ele começa a fazer o *download* e correr a barra até o final do *progress*. Existe um texto abaixo no `ProgressDialog` que significa a porcentagem e o tamanho total, no qual é definido automaticamente como mostra na imagem:

#### Imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Código

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.str_title_download_new_version));
                        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        progressDialog.show();
```

#### Configuração do Ambiente

- IDE: Eclipse Mars 2
- SDK Target: Android 2.3.3 - Api Level 10

#### Dúvida

Gostaria de concatenar duas letras no final do `1311/4140` para se referir aos *megabytes*, por exemplo: `Mb`. Fiz algumas pesquisas mas não obtive sucesso. Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa concatenação no `ProgressDialog`?

Abraços! =)

Comment: Posta o código que vc ta usando, fica melhor pra ajudar

Comment: @LeonardoDias talvez sim patrão. Abs.

Comment: @stderr não existe essa propriedade no progressDialog. Estou usando `import android.app.ProgressDialog`.

Comment: @stderr como eu disse ali nas **configurações de ambiente**, estou usando API 10.